# Data structure in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures, iterator

```
names=['Peter', 'John']
size = ['M', 'L']
list_price =  [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

I want to make my data structure into:

```
[{'size_price': [1,2],'size':['M','L'], 'name': 'Peter'}, 
 {'size_price': [4,5],'size':['M','L'],  'name': 'John'}]
```

Comment: It's a different data structure. Can you look at the data again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`zip`ping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) `names` with `list_price` does most of the work for you:

```
result = []
for name, prices in zip(names, list_price):
    result.append({"name": name, "size_price": prices, "size": size})
```